# Using query to validate date, but error in result

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I have a date column in a data table. The dates are stored in varchar format. I have used following query to identify whether the data are date format or not (thanks to @Digvijay Verma):

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
select *, ISDATE([DATE_OF_BIRTH]) as 'DOB' 
from [dbo].[IECLUniqueData4] 
where ISDATE([DATE_OF_BIRTH]) = 1
```

However this query failed to validate one data: 15/05/1

How can I modify this query so that it can also validate all the erroneous values? I have tried various things but none seems to work.

Regards,

Sadat

Comment: *The dates are stored in varchar format*. **Why?** Just use `Date[time]`

Comment: @MartinSmith: Because the data are manually updated in the SQL and the source is in varchar format. Converting the source to date time is creating problem due to erroneous data stored in the column.

Comment: So you should store this in a column of appropriate datatype and sort this out at insert time and reject invalid dates with an error. `SET DATEFORMAT dmy; select CAST('15/05/1' AS DATE)` returns `2001-05-15` BTW.

Comment: 15/05/1 is a valid dmy date. Why is it an invalid date in your case?

Comment: Leaving aside the funkiness of storing dates in varchar columns, that value is a valid date.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1e0f/2  Perhaps you're failing on a different value?

Comment: @Andrew: I think I am not failing into a different value. And that is not a date. Is there any way to redesign that query a certain way where it can identify 15/05/1 as not a date?